# How can i connect Raspberry pi Microphone over Bluetooth to my Phone/Computer

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, microphone, speaker

i hava following project, which i want to execute:
I want to add a Microphone on my Raspberry. After, i want to connect my raspberry over Bluetooth to my Phone/Computer. My goal is, to speak in the Microphone and the spoken Sound is sent to my Phone, which can be used as a Soundsource to response my friends on call or someting like this. So, it should act like a Handsfree facility. is this possible? Till now, i only heard of sending audio to my raspberry over bluetooth and put it out on a speaker on a raspberry, but i this project i want exactly the opposite. Can someone help me, to find a soulution? thanks